# Minimization problem and LASSO regression

Tags: statistics, regression, machine-learning

The points fall evenly inside the rectangle $a \times b$. The centre of the rectangle is in $(0,0)$.

Every time each point is approximated with two parameters: $p_1$ and $p_2$  so that $$|p_1| + |p_2| = c = const$$
and $$L = (p_1-x)^2 + (p_2-y)^2 \to min$$

What will be the probability of that $p_1 \cdot p_2$ $\neq 0$ ?

I had only one idea - to use LASSO regression Tibshirani but could not count probability. Maybe you have some ideas?

Comment: Assume wlog $a \le b$. You're looking for the projection of a point onto the $\ell_1$ ball of radius $c$. Drawing a figure might help (there will be 3 distinct regimes: $b<c, a< c \le b, c\le a$). By symmetry considerations, you only need to worry about the first quadrant (prove this). Now consider the situation where you have a point in the first quadrant, and you're projecting it onto the line $x+y = c.$ Show that if this projection lies outside the first quad, then the projection of this point on the ball $\|x\|_1 = c$ will be a corner point.